# vuejs/nuxtjs: updating url with new parameter resets all data to initial values

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a view categories/:name. When I load this view (E.g categories/portraits) everthing works . But if I change the url to categories/travel, all my data gets resetet to it's initial values.

That's my code

```
<template>
  // navigation
  <nuxt-link
    v-for="(category, index) in categories"
    :to="'/category/' + category.name"
  >
</template>

data() {
  return {
    galleriesFiltered: null,
    category: {},
    testData: 'INIT',
    thumbs: null
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('album',[
    'categories',
    'galleries'
  ])
},
//watch for updates in my url and load new data
watch: {
  '$route.params.name'(value){
   this.getData(value);
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.getData(this.$router.currentRoute.params.name);
},
methods: {
  getData(name) {
    console.log('load category', name);
    this.testData = 'set new DATA';
    //get current category
    this.category = this.categories.find(category => {
      return category.name === name
    });
    //get all related galleries to this category
    this.galleriesFiltered = this.galleries.filter(gallery => {
      return gallery.category_id === this.category.id
    })
    console.log(this.galleriesFiltered); //always outputs my galleries
  },
}
```

So in dev tools I can see this after I load the page the first time. That works
[image: after first load]

When I navigate to a new category all my data gets reseted. But if I log getData(). I get correct values, but it doesn't update my data object. It just gets reseted...

[image: after updating the view]
[image: logs]

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
key: to => to.name,
...
async asyncData (){
```

This way your page componen't won't reload but at the same time asyncData will be triggered.

And by the way, in nuxt (especially if you use SSR) you shouldn't watch route param, you shouldn't trigger data fetch in mounted hook. [This](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/async-data) is how it should be done.

Comment: hi :) The key attribute where I have to add it? To my nuxtchild? And my page isn't SSR I load all data in advance to my vuex and then I load from my views the data from there. So is asyncData still usefull for me?

Comment: @GregorOi you should add it where you'd add asyncData (this is why I added it to example code). In your case you don't have to use asyncData, but as for me, I'd still use it (or fetch in case of using vuex).